# Show or disprove: If A ∈ $\mathcal{F}$ is independent of itself, then either $P(A) = 0$ or $P(A) = 1$.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Show or disprove:

If A ∈ $\mathcal{F}$ is independent of itself, then either $P(A) = 0$ or $P(A) = 1$.

My "solution" is
$$P(A\cap A)=P(A)P(A)=P(A)^2 $$ but $P(A\cap A) = P(A)$, since $A = A \cap A $.

Therefore, $P(A)=P(A)P(A)=P(A)^2$.

This result only can occur when $P(A)=1$ or $P(A)=0$.

Is this enough to say, that our statement is true?

Comment: Then $P(A)=P(A)^2\implies P(A)(1-P(A))=0\implies ....$

Comment: Hint: that is $A\cap A$?

Comment: Yes, it's correct